# Multi-mastering syncing with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

**Use Case:** Currently we have "offices" in places around the world with very intermittent internet access. Sometimes it's great, but sometimes it can go off for hours at a time.

Right now we are using CouchDB that has a master database in the cloud and we have documents with an `office_id`. We then do a filtered sync to all of these "offices" to only send over documents that have that `office_id` and that are less than a month old.

With CouchDB you can edit these documents and add new ones on the offline CouchDB server in these offices. At this time, we have a cron that does a replication sync to our master database in the cloud every 5 minutes or so.

**Problem:** While CouchDB makes it really easy to sync, I'm afraid of some scalability issues with CouchDB. Before it gets too late, I'm trying to explore different database avenues and ways I could do this.

Amazon seems to be doubling down with their [DocumentDB](https://aws.amazon.com/documentdb/) offering that supports MongoDB so I'm curious: has anyone done multi-master syncing with MongoDB or an NoSQL equivalent?

I don't want to get into a scenario where scaling puts me in a corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon DocumentDB is using shared storage which isn't at all what you are after, and doesn't solve your problem. MongoDB would be a very poor choice for your scenario, and master-master replication is a really hard problem to deal with. CouchDB (like you use) is the first that pops to mind, but you should really search for that explicit feature if you are looking for a replacement. Also note that a lot of multi-master setups makes the assumption that a partitioning occur between masters, but the clients can still connect to all or some masters, which isn't your case because clients only have a single valid master.

Another option would be to build your replication yourself using a queue system or similar, but that would require even more infrastructure on each location (since the problem is the internet connection going down), and that would only be "easy" if different offices rarely or never edit the same documents, because manually having to deal with merging is a pain.

You don't explain what your scaling worries are, but I don't really see MongoDB or any other NoSQL database to have that much different scalability traits than CouchDB.

EDIT: What you are actually after is Optimistic Replication (or Lazy Replication, Eventual Consistency)

Comment: I really appreciate this in depth response. CouchDB is the only thing that seems to do it the multi master out of the box. It might be good to note that on the "local server" I'm always creating new documents and not updating.  My overall concern is with doing heavy analytics with CouchDB through indexes and how fast it'll be vs other databases. Or just finding a good solution of pushing data over to BigQuery or redshift etc.

Comment: @bryan I'd argue that analytics and the such doesn't belong in a production system, so your idea of pushing into another system where you can optimize the data (and indexes) for the analytics seems like a better solution. Even so, you might get away by having a replicating extra couchDB which you use as a read-only analytics storage until you start to reach an amount of data that gives you performance problem. Adding indexes comes with a cost though, so if you need indexes just for analytics you are already tainting the database in a bad way.

Comment: an extra couchdb or use this https://github.com/glynnbird/couchwarehouse. wouldn't worry about scalability with CouchDB. Cloudant is built off Apache CouchDB and powers IBM Cloud

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned a "NoSQL equivalent", I would like to explain how Couchbase can accomplish this in 2 different ways:

1) Cross Data Center Replication (XDCR) - Allow Clusters of different sizes to synchronize the data between them. The replication can be paused/resumed without any issues (conflicts can be solved via timestamp or document revision). Replications can be uni and bidirectional and you can also filter which documents should be syncronized between clusters using Filtering Expressions (A simplified query system) https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/xdcr-reference/xdcr-filtering-expressions.html

2) Sync Gateway - It is a middleware originally designed to synchronize your main database with a database on the edge. In this architecture, we assume that the connection will be down most of the time. https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-mobile-embedded-java-write-throughput/ . Your application could simply consume sync-gateway stream and insert the changes in the cluster replica. (Although I think XDCR should be enough for you)

Couchbase started as a fork of CouchDB a long time ago and most of the code has been rewritten, but some core concepts are still present in Couchbase.
Finally, a big plus of moving to Couchbase is that it is a distributed and highly scalable database ( from 1 to > 100 nodes in a single cluster) and you will be able to query your data using N1QL https://query-tutorial.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1